# Reset BigQuery Table from Spark ETL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, etl

I have a question for you. If I have an ETL built in Databricks that is loading data into BigQuery, but I want the BigQuery table to be wiped before each run of the ETL, is that possible? Sorry for the newbie question! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load data there are two properties (among many others) available under configuration.load property of jobs.insert that are useful to control what and how happens with the table you load into:

[`configuration.load.writeDisposition`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.writeDisposition)

> [Optional] Specifies the action that occurs if the destination table already exists.
>
> The following values are supported:
>   WRITE_TRUNCATE: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data. 
>   WRITE_APPEND: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.
>   WRITE_EMPTY: If the table already exists and contains data, a 'duplicate' error is returned in the job result.
>   The default value is WRITE_APPEND.
>
> Each action is atomic and only occurs if BigQuery is able to complete the job successfully. Creation, truncation and append actions occur as one atomic update upon job completion.

and

[`configuration.load.createDisposition`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.createDisposition)

> [Optional] Specifies whether the job is allowed to create new tables.
>
> The following values are supported:
>   CREATE_IF_NEEDED: If the table does not exist, BigQuery creates the table.
>   CREATE_NEVER: The table must already exist. If it does not, a 'notFound' error is returned in the job result.
>   The default value is CREATE_IF_NEEDED.
>
> Creation, truncation and append actions occur as one atomic update upon job completion.

So, `WRITE_TRUNCATE` is what you are looking for